# Thunderbird: remove "Customize from Address" from the identities list when sending email

Tags: thunderbird

When Thunderbird has several identities configured, normally the default identity is used when sending email. But other identity can be selected by clicking on the default address next to "From" field in the compose message window.

This is how it looked in previous versions of Thunderbird:

[image]

Now in new Thunderbird 68.8 the list of identities also contains menu to customize identities, called "Customize From Address...".

[image]

This is yet another example of idiotic change that always comes with new version of Thunderbird. As if, an operation that needs to be done only once, needed to be accessible every time identity is switched.

Anyway, is there a way to remove "Customize From Address..." from the list, so that only the identities are displayed, as it used to be in older Thunderbird?

Comment: I welcome this change. I use "customize from Address..." quite often. Even better you can also define a "catch all" address so that if you hit "reply", the reply will automatically use the received header email address as customized from address for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You have to patch again your `Omni.ja` file to remove it.

I have created a repository for the patches and this commit removes the `Customize From Address...` - [Removal of pop-up menu item - Customize From Address...](https://github.com/tukanos/customize-thunderbird/commit/e6c3edd3a112556ea0532baa0d469ca1f841d99f)

**Re-Edit: Remove the field all together**

*Note:* This can be tricky as this could change in the future.  The above patch does contain the box but will be more stable.

I have digged deep into the source code and the patches done at Thunderbird.   I have found different way to get rid of the box.

Here is a re-patch - [FromAddress box removal patch](https://github.com/tukanos/customize-thunderbird/commit/da915e1708e697b60b5db94ef25b0f9601155e9f), which patches a different part of the code, probably way safer than before.

What id does it comments out these lines, which place the `menuseparator` element and the `cmd_customizeFromAddress` into the pop-up list.

```
  menulist.menupopup.appendChild(document.createXULElement("menuseparator"));
  menulist.menupopup
    .appendChild(document.createXULElement("menuitem"))
    .setAttribute("command", "cmd_customizeFromAddress");
```

Still at the same file `chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messengercompose/MsgComposeCommands.js`

Comment: the patch does remove the text, but the empty field (now shrunken) remains. See screenshot:  https://paste.pics/1593f3d68e7e92e955658e56c4d9e1ee

Comment: @400theCat yes, that is true.  I'll try to figure out if I can hide it.

Comment: @400theCat I have found a way, but it can be tricky.  You have to do it manually as I did not yet create a patch way.

Comment: I think your last modification broke something. After deleting everything inside `function MakeFromFieldEditable(ignoreWarning) { }`, now the identities disappeared entirely - I don't even see my default identity. And a new attachment icon appeared, which was not there before. Bizarre. See screenshot: https://paste.pics/d0873313ce0f733d5a6a674d0c3cdecd

Comment: @400theCat I have came up with safer solution see, my re-edit

Comment: now it's perfect. Thank you.